# How can I mock/patch a method inside for specific method class?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest, pytest-mock

**Objective**: I'm trying to do a end to end test in an application. So I would like to mock the external communications to test all flow.

**Business problem**:

- `Bar` class equivalent: I have a class that send requests.

  2. bar_method -> send_request
- `Foo` class equivalent: is my user class that build the data to send requests.

  - method_that_use_bar_function -> create_user
  - method_that_use_bar_function_too -> get_user
- `runner` equivalent: is a job that executes some user's operations

**Reproducibility**:

To simplify the test developing, I build this code with similar structure to reproduce the scenario:

```
# / (root folder)
from src.foo import Foo

def method_to_run_all_my_code():
    my_foo = Foo()
    res1 = my_foo.method_that_use_bar_function()
    res2 = my_foo.method_that_use_bar_function_too()
    return res1 + res2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    method_to_run_all_my_code()

# src/foo.py
from .bar import Bar

class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.bar = Bar()
    
    def method_that_use_bar_function(self):
        result = self.bar.bar_method()
        print("[Foo] Use 1 - " + result)
        return "Use 1 - " + result
    
    def method_that_use_bar_function_too(self):
        result = self.bar.bar_method()
        print("[Foo] Use 2 - ", result)
        return "Use 2 - " + result


# src/bar.py
class Bar:

def bar_method(self):
    print("[Bar] this is a real method of bar")
    return "real method"
```

I would like to mock the bar_method when it is called by `method_that_use_bar_function` (not `method_that_use_bar_function_too`), for example.

I tried these tests, but I can’t do this yet.

```
# tests/runner_test.py
import unittest
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
from runner import method_to_run_all_my_code


@pytest.mark.skip() # this use the real values
def test_initial():
    res = method_to_run_all_my_code()
    assert "Use 1" in res
    assert "Use 2" in res


@pytest.mark.skip() # this mock Foo method
@patch("src.foo.Foo.method_that_use_bar_function", return_value="Mocked foo function use 1")
def test_mocking_bar_for_use_1(mocked_use_1):
    res = method_to_run_all_my_code()
    print("Final Results: ", res)
    assert "Mocked foo function use 1" in res
    assert "Use 2" in res


@pytest.mark.skip()
@patch("src.foo.Bar.bar_method", return_value="Bar function was mocked") # mock bar method for both use 1 and 2. I don't want this.
def test_mocking_bar_method(mocked_bar):
    res = method_to_run_all_my_code()
    print("Final Results: ", res)
    assert "1 - Bar function was mocked" in res
    assert "2 - Bar function was mocked" in res


@pytest.mark.skip() # this raise error
@patch("src.foo.Foo.method_that_use_bar_function", return_value=Mock(bar_method=Mock(return_value="Bar function was mocked to use 1")))
def test_mocking_bar_for_use_1(mocked_bar_use_1):
    res = method_to_run_all_my_code()
    print("Final Results: ", res)
    assert "Mocked foo function use 1" in res
    assert "Use 2" in res


@pytest.mark.skip() # this raise error
@patch("src.foo.Foo.method_that_use_bar_function.Bar.bar_method", return_value="Bar function was mocked to use 1")
def test_mocking_bar_for_use_1(mocked_bar_use_1):
    res = method_to_run_all_my_code()
    print("Final Results: ", res)
    assert "Mocked foo function use 1" in res
    assert "Use 2" in res


if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: The original posting is an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) question. What is the underlying business problem you are trying to solve? That is, why do you feel it is important for `all_my_code()` to invoke both the real and the mocked `bar_method()` within a single call? Also, tell us how much latitude you have to alter the `Bar` class, its public API, and its attributes. As it stands, it appears you are needlessly imposing too-difficult constraints on the solution space. Allowing extra args or attributes would make things easier.

Comment: @J_H Thanks for the advice, I didn't know about de XY question concept! I updated the description of question, is it better? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

The point of a
test double
is to let a unit test focus on the target code
it wishes to exercise, without worrying about
the expense (delay) or possible bugs of collaborating code,
such as high level

- `create_user`
- `get_user`

or low level `send_request` methods.

Automated tests that interact with "the next layer down",
such as create / get user,
can sensibly be called "unit" tests.
But tests that probe through one layer
to an underlying one that contains `send_request`
are more properly labeled "integration" tests.

Changing the implementation of `send_request`
for `create_user`, but reverting it to
usual behavior for `get_user`, seems like
a bridge too far for simple mocks to tackle.
Apparently you've already considered mocking `send_request`
for the entire duration of a unit test,
and have rejected that approach.

It sounds like you want to introduce some
[DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)
into the target code's Public API,
so that alternate network transports
(such as a mocked `send_request`)
can be supplied as a parameter.

Either that, or you might want to supply
a pair of mocked methods which do
the Right Thing in each {production, test} environment,
*without* altering support routines they invoke,
such as `send_request`.